# Regex or String Manipulation by IndexOf?

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, time

I have to replace in a string the characters before and after the occurrence of the matched word.

I was wondering:

**1.**  if the ***functionality*** is better when I use a regex or when we use indexOf, loops etc.?

**2.**  what is considered a more ***readable code***: regex or using indexOf, iterating through the string, etc.?

**3.** in means of ***time complexity***, in which way the complexity is decreased.

**Just to clarify, what I am asking is what is better using regex or just doing string manipulation. See my  questions above**

Comment: Can you show us what the string and its replacement are?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, added an example.

Comment: Probably the most efficient you could do would be to simply matching [`(abc)|.`](https://regex101.com/r/JlRaru/5) and while going through matches, if group one is set, append `group(1)` to a new string, else append `*`. Also see [The Best Regex Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). Or you could do one `replaceAll()` with a [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) based pattern like [`(?:(?<=abc)|\G)(?!abc).`](https://regex101.com/r/JlRaru/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative solution using a formal Java regex pattern matcher:

```
String input = "abc1111abc3434";
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String pattern = "((?!abc).)*abc";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    String replace = m.group(0).replaceAll(".", "*");
    replace = replace.substring(0, replace.length()-3) + "abc";
    m.appendReplacement(buffer, replace);
}
int length = buffer.length();
m.appendTail(buffer);
String result = buffer.substring(0, length) + buffer.substring(length).replaceAll(".", "*");
System.out.println(result);
```

This prints:

```
abc****abc****
```

The trick being used here is the following regex pattern:

```
((?!abc).)*abc
```

This will match any content which is *not* the sequence `abc`, but which ends in `abc`.  That is, the first portion of this pattern is the actual content you want to mask with `***`.  At each match, we append to the StringBuffer the masked content followed by the `abc` marker.  Note that this creates an edge case.  After all replacements have been made, there might be a tail of non `abc` content.  In this case, we just mask the entire substring and append to the StringBuffer.

Comment: see my question edit.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer.  I don't think there is a pure regex solution in Java, and my answer uses both regex and string manipulation.

Comment: See @Jigar Gajjar's answer, he has regex for this

Answer (score -1):

Invokve `close()` method, once your usage of the resource is completed.

This ensures the resource is closed, and clears the allocated memory.

In your case it will be,

```
input1.close();
```

and

```
input2.close();
```

After your both results are printed.

Detailed API for scanner (JDK8) : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score -1):

```
String str ="abc1111abc3434";
System.out.println( str.replaceAll("[^\"abc\"]", "*"));
```

Comment: This regex works well, but can you address my specific questions?